# Representable class: undefined method nested for. How can I solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the `nested` method from [representable gem](https://github.com/apotonick/representable) but I'm getting this message: `undefined method 'nested' for OrdersRepresenter.`

I already put the gem im my Gemfile.

This is my class:

```
class OrdersRepresenter < Representable::Decorator
  include Representable::JSON

    nested :body do 
      collection :orders
    end
end
```

I also have roar-rails in my Gemfile

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I din't have representable updated in my Gemfile.

I endup doing:

```
gem 'representable', '~> 1.7.7'
```

and

```
bundle update representable
```